# Analyzing pixel RGB values with PIL

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I need to find the RGB values of each pixel in a picture. How could I do this using PIL? I know that Pillow is better, but since I only need to do this one thing I thought I could just use PIL. If this won't work as well please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("filename.png")
pixels = img.load()

#get the B value of the pixel at x=23, y=42
print pixels[23, 42][2]
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is a good solution but just suggesting another way which is one line:

```
from scipy import misc;

imgData = misc.imread('./image.png');
```

You can then easily get the colors at every pixels you need.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin got it pretty much spot on, you can also use `getdata()` to return a list of tuples.

I may have got this totally wrong, but `load()` might work better if you need particular pixels, and `getdata()` if you need all of them. Also, it's a good idea to convert to RGB if it's just a normal image, I've had errors before by not doing that.

```
image = Image.open('filename').convert('RGB')
width, height = image.size

#Get pixels in a list of tuples
pixels = image_input.getdata()

#If you need a flat list containing all the colours
bytes = [j for i in pixels for j in i]
```

If you needed to do stuff to the pixels and rebuild the image after, that's where the image size comes in useful.